# WordPress > display all categories, subcategories and sub-subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use php to display all categories and subcategories in a WordPress website like this:

- Category

  - Subcategory

    - Sub-Subcategory
  - Subcategory

    - Sub-Subcategory
    - Sub-Subcategory

The problem is that so far i can only get the Category and Subcategory part but i can't get the Sub-Subcategory thing :(

Here is the code that i'm using(i found it on stackoverflow but it doesn't show sub-subcategories :( ):

```
<?php

    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $orderby      = 'name';  
    $show_count   = 0;      
    $pad_counts   = 0;      
    $hierarchical = 1;      
    $title        = '';  
    $empty        = 0;

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty
    );

    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {

        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {

            $category_id = $cat->term_id;

            echo '<br /> ('. $category_id .') <a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

            $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );

            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );

            if($sub_cats) {

                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                    echo  '<br/> > <a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a>';
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' (' . $sub_category->count . ')', $category );
                }
            }
        }       
    }
?>
```

I think that i somehow need to get the subcategory id in order to be able to list all sub-subcategorie but the problem is that i can't find a way to get the subcategory id...so far i can only get the category id :(

Comment: The sub category id can be accessed using `$sub_category->term_id`

Comment: oh :D thank you! now the only problem that i can think of is that for each and every sub-level i have to create a new foreach and a new set of args, right? :-?